# ANSI C - what does struct **variable mean?

Tags: c, gcc

In ANSI C, what does `struct **variable` mean? For example:

```
typedef struct estructuraPersona{
  char nombre[30];
  char apellido[30];
} tyPersona;

typedef tyPersona *ptrTyPersona;

ptrTyPersona functionFive(ptrTyPersona *ptrPtrTyPersona) {
  ptrTyPersona *pptP= (ptrTyPersona *)malloc(sizeof(tyPersona));
  if (*pptP == NULL) {
    printf("Error al crear nuevo nodo!");
    return NULL;
  }
  return pptP;
}
```

I get an error when compiling the code.

Comment: you declared return type of `fuctionFive()` as `ptrTyPersona` but returning `ptrTyPersona *`

Comment: `typedef tyPersona *ptrTyPersona;` you are confusing yourself by hiding a pointer behind a typedef.

Comment: There is no `struct **variable` in your code. Please correct either the question or the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
ptrTyPersona* functionFive(ptrTyPersona *ptrPtrTyPersona){
```

instead of

```
ptrTyPersona functionFive(ptrTyPersona *ptrPtrTyPersona){
```

Comment: not necessarily the right solution ; he is mallocing `sizeof(tyPersona)` and it's not clear if he wants to return `ptrTyPersona` pointing to a struct instance, or do what you suggest and return a pointer to a malloc'd pointer (which does not point to a struct yet).

Comment: His problem was the warning.

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
ptrTyPersona functionFive(ptrTyPersona *ptrPtrTyPersona){
  ptrTyPersona *pptP= (ptrTyPersona *)malloc(sizeof(tyPersona));
  if(*pptP == NULL){
    printf("Error al crear nuevo nodo!");
    return NULL;
  }
  return pptP;
}
```

makes no sense because parameter `ptrPtrTyPersona` is not used.

I can suspect that the function should do the following

```
ptrTyPersona functionFive(ptrTyPersona *ptrPtrTyPersona){
  *ptrPtrTyPersona = ( ptrTyPersona )malloc(sizeof(tyPersona));

  if(*ptrPtrTyPersona == NULL){
    printf("Error al crear nuevo nodo!");
  }

  return *ptrPtrTyPersona;
}
```

As for the original function then function return type is `ptrTyPersona` but the function returns pointer `pptP` of type `ptrTyPersona *`

And in this statement

```
  ptrTyPersona *pptP= (ptrTyPersona *)malloc(sizeof(tyPersona));
```

there is allocated structure tyPersona so you should use pointer of type `ptrTyPersona` to refer the allocated memory but you use pointer of type `ptrTyPersona *`